# Writing File not anymore working in TiSDK 5.2.0 / Android 6.0

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In TiSDK 5.1.2.GA this example below works fine also in Android 6.x without the user giving explicit permission for this app.

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow();
var sourceFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(
    Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory).nativePath,
    "andylution.jpg"
);
var destFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(
Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.getApplicationDataDirectory(true)).nativePath,
    'andylution.jpg'
);

if (sourceFile.exists() && destFile.exists() === false) {
    destFile.write(sourceFile.read());
}

win1.add(Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: destFile
}));

win1.open();
```

But when I update to TiSDK 5.2.0.GA the destFile is not more readable untill the user permits the app to use the storage.

What confuses me most is the fact, that the destFile in both versions has the same File.URL.

Am I doing sth. wrong or is there a bug?

Comment: There is issue in TiSDK 5.2.0 https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20440

Comment: Added a watch to the ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Android 6, you should give explicit permission at least once to access file storage,
even if using 5.1.2.GA, i tried it before.

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow();
if (!Ti.Media.hasCameraPermissions()) {
    Titanium.Media.requestCameraPermissions(function() {
       var sourceFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory).nativePath, "andylution.jpg");
       var destFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.getApplicationDataDirectory(true)).nativePath,'andylution.jpg');

       if (sourceFile.exists() && destFile.exists() === false) {
          destFile.write(sourceFile.read());
       }

       win1.add(Ti.UI.createImageView({
         image: destFile
       }));
       win1.open();
    });
```